# Post json object to controller and get view

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0, devextreme

I am trying to post data to a different action in the same controller. All these days i used use form submit or url with query parameters, my present case is different:

requirement: in one of the views we have some dropdowns, textboxes and dynamically generated divs (Tiles), each div is clickable, now when user clicks on a div(Tile), the javascript function is called which grabs dropdown control's value, textbox value, Now i need to post that data to a different action (lets say actionMethod2) in the same controller and display whatever view it returns back, how do i do that ?

I tried using ajax post method, but realized i can not move to the view returned by that actionMethod2. 
And i tried to do a simple window.location but i need to post the values too...

here is the javascript:

```
    var searchModel = {};
    searchModel.StartDate = $('#dvSearchDateRange').attr('data-startDt');
    searchModel.EndDate = $('#dvSearchDateRange').attr('data-endDt');
    searchModel.Status = propertyName;
    searchModel.StatusText = tileText;
    searchModel.AgencyId = cascadOADdropdowns.selectedAgencyId;
    searchModel.DeptId = cascadOADdropdowns.selectedDeptId;
    searchModel.AgencyName = cascadOADdropdowns.selectedAgencyName;
    searchModel.DeptName = cascadOADdropdowns.selectedDeptName;
    $.ajax({
        url: referralSearchUrl, // /Home/ReferralsList'
        type:"POST",
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: "json",
        data: JSON.stringify(searchModel)
    });
```

this technically works but thats not what i want, i need to display entire view returned by the action method (like as if you called from url).

```
HomeController:
//this method provides data to dynamically generate divs. You can consider this as user's landing view(Page)
    public ActionResult Index(DashboardSearchViewModel vm)
    {
        //VMs
        UserInfoViewModel userInfoVM = MySession.GetSession<UserInfoViewModel>(Constants.USER_INFO);
        LookupsViewModal lookupsVM = new LookupsViewModal();
        //DAL, BAL
        DashboardBA dashboardBA = new DashboardBA();
        LookupsBA lookupsBA = new LookupsBA();

        vm.SearchStartDate = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-dateRange);
        vm.SearchEndDate = DateTime.Now;
        lookupsVM.AgencyId = vm.AgencyID = userInfoVM.UserInforFromES.AgencyID;
        lookupsVM.DeptId = vm.DepartmentID = userInfoVM.UserInforFromES.DeptID;
        lookupsVM.OrgId = userInfoVM.UserInforFromES.OrgID;
        lookupsVM.logonId = userInfoVM.LogonID;
        vm.LoggedInUserInformation = userInfoVM;
        vm = dashboardBA.GetDashboardSummary(vm);

        lookupsVM = lookupsBA.GetLookups(lookupsVM);

        TempData[Constants.LOOKUPS] = lookupsVM;
        return View(vm);
    }

    /*This is the action method i need to post values to and display returned view.Its like submitting data by user and redirect user to different view (by server)*/

    public ActionResult ReferralsList(ReferralSearchFilersViewModel searchValues)
    {
      return View(vm);
    }
```

Comment: The whole point of ajax is to stay on the same page. If you want to _redirect user to different view_, then do not use ajax. Just do a notmal submit.

Comment: @Stephen: You are right, I should not use Ajax. But i need to collect some data on the page displayed using javascript and submit it to the controller then controller redirects me to different view. Now i am not sure how we do that we are not using any form here ....

Comment: But why not just add `<form>` tags?

Comment: The content i am displaying is displayed dynamically using jquery calls and some front end tools. And when user clicks on one of the divs, i need to grab some values (based on which div user clicked on) and post them  to server, if everything looks good on server side the action method will redirect else, it will send error message.

Comment: What you say about that: you send ajax request and if it completes without errors then redirect user to another view (somthing like window.location = '/controller/action'). Else you show some error to the user?

Answer (score 0):

Change your action to return a `PartialViewResult`. You may need to set `@{ Layout = null }` in your partial razor view.

In the `success` callback of your JQuery ajax call, populate some `<div>` on your page with the results of the partial. e.g.

```
$.ajax({
    url: referralSearchUrl, // /Home/ReferralsList'
    type:"POST",
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: "json",
    data: JSON.stringify(searchModel),
    success: function(partial) {
        $('#SomeDiv').html(partial);
    }
});
```

Comment: In our case we need to display complete view including the Layout, as the returned view uses different Layout and bunch of javascript files references and some images.

Comment: Are you embedding the returned view in a "parent" view? You could always keep the Action returning an ActionResult (normal view) and you would still receive all the html in the partial parameter passed to the success callback.